# Rule based rendering, Leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet, gis

Is there an argument in Leaflet for R that allows for rule-based rendering? I want a `labelOnlyMarker` layer to render only when the map is zoomed in beyond a certain level.

This map is *not* for a Shiny app. Any solutions that I have seen are performed in a Shiny app, and rely on an event observation.

Thanks :)

Comment: if you install from github, you can use `groupOptions` to specify the zoom levels at which each group should be shown

Comment: Thank you! I made the switch to the github version, and it does exactly what I want it to.